# Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.3

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, haar-classifier

I have a problem in my code to detect someone's face in python2.7 and opencv3.3

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
rec=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
rec.load("recognizer/trainningData.yml")
id=0
font=cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,5,1,0,4)
while(True):
    ret,img=cam.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rextangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
        id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        if id is 1:
            id="Zakir Naik"
        elif id is 2:
            id="Erdogan"
        elif id is 3:
            id="Fachrul"
        cv2.cv.PutText(cv2.cv.fromarray(img),str(id),(x,y+h),font,255)
    cv2/imshow("Face",img)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord("q")):
        break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output

```
'cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for the `LBPHFaceRecognizer_create` object? Can you find the `load` function you are trying to call?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV2 has a load function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.3/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html)

[OpenCV3 does not](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html)

Maybe try `rec.read("recognizer/trainningData.yml")`